# Linux Programs for pulling measurements from graphics

Tags: linux, graphics, adobe-fireworks

As a front-end developer, I'm often given graphics of web sites and told pretty much, "Make it work." I've recently started working on Linux 100% of the time and was wondering if there's any programs out there that're good for "digesting" graphics.

All I do, pretty much, is draw little selection boxes and takes notes on their dimensions; I also slice out a piece of the graphic (i.e. copy out just the part of the graphic I need for to make the same effect in CSS). Before now I've been *very* happy with Fireworks, but I need something for Linux, any suggestions?

As a note, I mainly deal with pixel based graphics, so the program being vector based isn't a necessity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIMP. It has a bit of a learning curve, but it can be extremely powerful when used right. Depending on your distro, it might already be installed, otherwise http://www.gimp.com/downloads

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to look into using this more, I've known about GIMP for a while but always wrote it off as something along the lines of MSPaint. Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: Gimp is closer to Photoshop than MSPaint